# I have a question about ATR Bands in FineScript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a question about ATR Bands in FineScript.

Find out the value of the upper closing price of the atr band and the value of the /lower closing price when entering the strategy, and then TP and stop-loss from that value...Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it is possible. You need to use the `var` keyword to store the value of the upper/lower band at the time of your entry. Then later use that variable as your TP/SL.

```
var float atr_upper_band = na
atr_upper_band  := entry_condition ? upper_band_value : atr_upper_band  // Store the upper band value if it is a new entry. Keep the old value otherwise
```

The key here is to use `var` keyword so their values don't change unless you specifically do it.

> **var** is the keyword used for assigning and one-time initializing of the
> variable.\
>
> Normally, a syntax of assignment of variables, which doesn’t
> include the keyword var, results in the value of the variable being
> overwritten with every update of the data. Contrary to that, when
> assigning variables with the keyword var, they can “keep the state”
> despite the data updating, only changing it when conditions within
> if-expressions are met.

Comment: Thank you, teacher!
May I ask you one more question?

Comment: --------------------------------------------------
The above is before the change.
The contents below are after the change.

Is it right to change it like this?
-------------------------------------------------

Comment: Yes but you should use only one `strategy.exit()`. You can combine your TP and SL in one `strategy.exit()`. Also, for TP, you should use the `limit` argument. `strategy.exit("LongExit", "Long", stop=atr_lower_band , limit=atr_upper_band)`